# How to handle dates if they are null on Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to decode a field called `noteLastUpdateDate` with `DateTime.parse()` from JSON but it is a nullable field so if it is null `DateTime.parse()` method throws an exception like this:

`Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid date format.`

Do you have any recommendations to fix this?

Here is the code:
[image]

Comment: Please post you code as text instead of a photo. I don't want to download a piece of OCR software to try out your example... :)

Comment: Also, what do you want to happen if the field is null? Should the dateTime field just also be null?

Answer (score 10):

New null safety `tryParse` method is available:

```
DateTime.tryParse(map['isoDate'].toString())
```

Docs:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/tryParse.html

Answer (score 2):

Are you expecting `note_last_update_date` to be updated before checking it?

You can use a `try/on` clause to handle `null` format exceptions:

```
...
try:
 parsedJSON['note_text'].toString()
 DateTime.parse(parsedJSON['note_last_update_date'].toString())
on FormatException:
 print('Invalid format - datetime is null')
...
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid NRE(Null Reference Exception) you need to write something like:

```
return Note(
  parsedJson[note_text].toString),
  parsedJson['note_last_update_date']==null? 
             null
             :DateTime.parse(parsedJson['note_last_update_date']);
```

But I prefer to use package [json_annotation](https://pub.dev/packages/json_annotation) for json parsing or [json2dart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) tool for avoiding such mistakes when working with json